# Customizing Bulma with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, bulma

I try to customize the Bulma default yellow colors for my Next.js project.

I have one global Sass file where I am changing the default `$yellow` and `$warning` color. However, when I import this file in my `_app.js`, nothing happens.

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables"

$yellow: #dc7185
$warning: $yellow

@import "bulma/css/bulma.css"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to overwrite Sass variables you'll want to import the Sass file rather than the CSS one.

```css
/* You global Sass file */

$yellow: #dc7185;
$warning: $yellow;

@import "~bulma/bulma.sass";
```

Comment: Thank you very much @juliomalves